# Wrong charset in Product options in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.1.0

I upgraded to Magento 2.1.0 from Magento 2.0.7 and now on product page Product options-container have wrong charset. I tried already change to default theme but it didn't help. Elsewhere on the product page characters are displayed correctly.
[image: Product page]

Comment: It seems more a DB or WebServer issue, can you pls check the default encoding in your webserver? My guess is that an additional encoding has been introduced in M2.1 breaking your product view

Comment: @RiccardoT : In DB (utf8_general_ci) and admin panel characters are displayed correctly.  I added `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to _apache2.conf_ but it had no effect.